# Jquery search doesn't find a symbols

Tags: jquery, regex

I have an text input and input button. I want to prevent input from numbers.

```
<input type="text" name="lastNameSend" id="lastNameSend" placeholder="Surname" class="sendFormInput"></input>
<input id="sendPhysButton" class="button button_at_left" type="submit">
```

I use jquery regexp  for it:

```
$(document).on("click","#sendPhysButton", function(event)
{
    if ($("#lastNameSend").val().search("/[0-9]*/i"))
    {
        alert($("#lastNameSend").val().search("/[0-9]*/i"));
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

For some reason it always alerts -1. When I enter numbers it is -1, when I enter letters it is -1.
Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jupnzty0/3/
What's wrong?

Comment: `search` is part of JS, not jQuery. Just remove the quotes (and the `i` - since it is redundant).

Comment: if you want to prevent numbers then use a negated character class.

Comment: I removed quotes. Stopped working at all.

Comment: Actually I need regex later when I will check if email valid.

Comment: Ah, you also need to remove `*`, otherwise, it will always return a match. So the correct code should be `search(/[0-9]/)` or even shorter `search(/\d/)`. It will return -1 if not found, and >= 0 (the index) if found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot going on here that gets in the way, but the two big ones are quoting the regex, and using '*'. Try this: `alert($("#lastNameSend").val().search(/\d/));` I also updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jupnzty0/10/)

Answer (score 2):

### String.search semantics

[`String.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) takes in a RegExp. If a non-RegExp object `obj` is passed in (in your case, it is a String), it is implicitly converted to a RegExp object by using `new RegExp(obj)`.

If successful, `search` returns the index of the first match of the regular expression inside the string. Otherwise, it returns -1.

Reproduced from MDN Reference.

### How to pass argument to String.search

Note that `/<regexp>/<flags>` is the syntax of the RegExp literal. When you pass in a string to RegExp constructor, you only need to pass in `<regexp>`, plus the flags in the second argument. For example, `new RegExp("[a-z]", "i")` and `/[a-z]/i` are equivalent in term of functionality (if there is any difference, that is the former is an object, the latter is a literal).

Note that [String literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) and RegExp literal have different rules for escaping special character. For example, `new RegExp("\\\\/")` and `/\\\//` are functionally equivalent, both of which test for the substring `\/`.

### Solution

Back to your code, there are a few problems:

- The quote means that you are passing `"/[0-9]*/i"` as a String, and the implicit conversion causes it to try to match for `/`, then 0 or more digits, then `/`, then `i`.
- Removing the quotes, `/[0-9]*/i` can match empty string due to `*` **zero** or more quantifier, which mean that it can find a match in any string.
- `i` flag is redundant - it doesn't affect `[0-9]`.
- `[0-9]` can be shorten to `\d`, but not a must.
- Your handling of the return value is incorrect. If you want to check that the regex does match the regex, compare the index returned by `>= 0`. If you want to check that the regex does **not** match the regex. compare the index returned by `< 0`.

The correct solution would be:

```
if ($("#lastNameSend").val().search(/[0-9]/) >= 0) {
    // Found invalid character
}
```

If you want to pass a string, `"[0-9]"` works as well.

There is an even terser method - [`RegExp.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), which returns `true` if the pattern is found in the string and `false` otherwise:

```
if (/[0-9]/.test($("#lastNameSend").val())) {
    // Found invalid character
}
```